# List with Int as first argument and String as second (Java)

Tags: java, indexing, arguments

I'm trying to write a method that returns an int index as the first argument and a string as the second. The method should insert the string into a list by order of the index's.  If the Int is negative or leaves a gap, it should throw IllegalArgumentException. Here's what I've done:

```
public MitchList() {
    data = new String[2];
    size = 0;
}
public int size() {
    return size;
}
    public void add(int index, String s){
    if (data.length == size) {
        String[] newArray = new String[data.length*2];
        for (int i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
            newArray[i] = data[i];
        }
        data = newArray;
}
    if (index > 0 || index <size){
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();   
    }

    if (data[index] != ""){
        for (int i = 0; i <size; i++){ 
        s = data[index];
        }
    }
    data[index] = s;
    size++;
```

}

The JUnit test is saying it is failing. It should return a list like:

1, Cat
2, Dog
3, Squirrel

So on..

Any ideas on a solution?

UPDATE

Here's what I have now.

```
/**
  <P>{@code java MitchList}</P>
**/
  public class MitchList  {
  private String[] asData;
  private int iSize;
  public static final void main(String[] igno_red)  {
     MitchList ml = new MitchList();
     test(ml, 0, "hello");
     test(ml, 1, "goodbye");
  }
  public static final void test(MitchList m_l, int i_ndex, String s_tring)  {
     m_l.add(i_ndex, s_tring);

     System.out.print(s_tring + ", ");
  }
  public MitchList() {
      asData = new String[2];
      iSize = 2;
  }
  public int iSize() {
      return iSize;
  }

      public void add(int index, String s){
  System.out.println("asData.length=" + asData.length + ", iSize=" + iSize + "");
      if (asData.length == iSize) {
  System.out.println("1");
          String[] newArray = new String[asData.length*2];
          for (int i=0; i < asData.length; i++) {
              newArray[i] = asData[i];
          }
          asData = newArray;
  }
      if (index > 0 || index <iSize){
  System.out.println("2");
 throw new IllegalArgumentException("index (" + index + ") must be greater than zero    and less than size (" + iSize + ")"); 

       }
  System.out.println("asData[" + index + "]=" + asData[index] + "");

      if (asData[index] != ""){
  System.out.println("3");
          for (int i = 0; i <iSize; i++){
  System.out.println("i=" + i + ", setting s to ");
             s = asData[index];
          }
      }
      asData[index] = s;
      iSize++;
  }
```

I took your code and changed a bit. Now it just gives back

```
  asData.length=2, iSize=2
```

1
2

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: index (0) must be greaterthan zero and less than size (2)
at MitchList.add(MitchList.java:42)
at MitchList.test(MitchList.java:14)
at MitchList.main(MitchList.java:10)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you trying to store int in a String array?

Comment: first, `data.length` will return 2 while `size` will return 0 on the initial call and therefore will skip the `newArray`-segment. Next, you throw an IllegalArgumentException if you provide any positive index - intended? negative indices are ok - they will later lead to IndexOutOfBound exceptions?

Comment: I'm still struggling to understand the intention of the last bit of your code TBH - the for-loop is useless as you don't use the run-index `i` at all. Moreover, if a value has already been assigned to that index, it will simply override the value passed as parameter - instead of doing the bottom block you could have used a simple if-statement that checks if the value in `data[index] == null` and if this is true assign s to the `data[index]` field.

Comment: Jarmaloon: Questions: Does "Mitch list" mean anything, or is that just a random name? Do you need to use arrays, or are other data-structures (such as `ArrayList`s) a possibility? And why are you doubling the length of the array (with `data.length*2`), yet only increasing `size` by one?

Comment: MitchList is just random. I think I can just use an array for this. I was asking to simply make a list that would implement said code, nothing specific. And as for the size increase, I suppose that's just a mistake on my part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very hard to get out what you are doing, with as little information you are giving us here, but this is what I've figured so far. Below is your code with some debugging statements in it.

I strongly recommend you add some information to your no-message exception. That is, change

```
throw new IllegalArgumentException();
```

to

```
throw new IllegalArgumentException("index (" + index + ") must be greater than zero and less than size (" + iSize + ")");
```

When I run this code, this is the output

```
[R:\jeffy\programming\sandbox\xbnjava]java MitchList
asData.length=2, iSize=0
asData[0]=null
3
hello,
asData.length=2, iSize=1
2
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: index (1) must be greater than zero and less than
 size (1)
        at MitchList.add(MitchList.java:41)
        at MitchList.test(MitchList.java:14)
    at MitchList.main(MitchList.java:11)
```

You were hiding some very valuable information: *Greater than zero and less than one is impossible*

Also

- You're doubling the size of the array with `data.length*2`, yet you're only increasing `size` by one: `size++;`.
- You're overwriting the value of `s` with *every* value in the array (the `s = data[index];` in the for-loop), causing it to always equal the last element. Then you're just re-inserting the *current* value of the last element over-top itself. In other words, the `s` parameter is being ignored, and the array is never changing.
- One more thought: I think `if(data[index] == "")` should be `if(data[index] == null)`. String arrays are initialized to `null`, not the empty-string.

Consider using the below code, with all its debugging statements, as a starting point for fixing the above issues, and discovering whatever others there may be. Good luck!

```
   import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
   /**
      <P>{@code java MitchList}</P>
    **/
   public class MitchList  {
      private String[] asData;
      private int iSize;
      public static final void main(String[] igno_red)  {
         MitchList ml = new MitchList();
         test(ml, 0, "hello");
         test(ml, 1, "goodbye");
      }
      public static final void test(MitchList m_l, int i_ndex, String s_tring)  {
         m_l.add(i_ndex, s_tring);

         //Print the array at the last index in asData
         System.out.println(StringUtils.join(m_l.asData, ", "));

        //If you don't have `commons.lang` installed, use this:
        //
        //   for(String s : asData)  {
        //      System.out.print(s + ", ");
        //   }
      }
      public MitchList() {
          asData = new String[2];
          iSize = 0;
      }

      public int iSize() {
          return iSize;
      }


          public void add(int index, String s){
System.out.println("asData.length=" + asData.length + ", iSize=" + iSize + "");
          if (asData.length == iSize) {
System.out.println("1");
              String[] newArray = new String[asData.length*2];
              for (int i=0; i < asData.length; i++) {
                  newArray[i] = asData[i];
              }
              asData = newArray;
      }
          if (index > 0 || index <iSize){
System.out.println("2");
             throw new IllegalArgumentException("index (" + index + ") must be greater than zero and less than size (" + iSize + ")");
          }
System.out.println("asData[" + index + "]=" + asData[index] + "");

          if (asData[index] != ""){
System.out.println("3");
              for (int i = 0; i <iSize; i++){
System.out.println("i=" + i + ", setting s to ");
                 s = asData[index];
              }
          }
          asData[index] = s;
          iSize++;
      }
}
```

Comment: s/he definitely tried to capture negative values but mixed up `>` with `<` - small but dramatic impact. Instead of printing tons of debug-information a simple single-step through debug-session in the editor of her/his choice would lead to the goal as well without having to alter the code to much

Comment: Well, I'm more comfortable with this approach. You don't need to use this many debugging statements, but certainly a few in some important locations are valuable. Especially for beginners who aren't comfortable with a debugger yet. Afraid to say it, but I've never used one myself, in many years of coding.

Comment: for this small sample-code sysouts are ok, but on larger projects I prefer debug-session rather than having to follow the path through some log-files. I use them to narrow down the problem and to decide on where to hook into the application. I have to admit however, that logs are important especially when dealing with concurrent execution and with n-tear infrastructure as this is sometimes a pain to debug

Comment: This is great! Thanks so much. I added some info to the description in hopes of it being a bit more explanatory. Again, thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I've been starting to think about learning about debuggers. I don't use an IDE (I program in TextPad, and use PhraseExpress for auto-completes), so we'll see what's the best approach. I'm pretty ignorant about it all, but I've made it this far  :)

Comment: @aliteralmind don't get me wrong but the only thing you actually did was to include "debug-statements" and to improve the exceptin-message to the non-functional code. Though, the logical errors are still present in the code - at least you could have fixed them so Jarmaloon may learn what he did wrong

Comment: Did my further explanation of the problem explain more what I'm trying to do?

Comment: well, just include some hints on what he is failing logically and how he could solve this and you deserve the answer. I'm not greedy or something like that, but an answer should contain a bit more ... quality in my opinion ;)

Comment: Added a few key observations. Hope this is better   :D

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Additional comment regarding `if (index > 0 || index <iSize)`. Aside from the or/and issue mentioned below, why must the index be *above* zero? Zero is a valid array index.

This is what I get when I run your updated code:

```
asData.length=2, iSize=2
1
2
asData[0]=null
3
i=0, setting s to
i=1, setting s to
hello, asData.length=4, iSize=3
2
asData[1]=null
3
i=0, setting s to
i=1, setting s to
i=2, setting s to
goodbye,
```

All of those `i=0, setting s to` is a problem. Why are you setting `s` to *anything*, let alone setting it repeatedly? And then you set that value into the array, which makes no sense, because that's where it *just* came from. To emphasize: *The parameter `s` is being over-written before you ever use it, and the array* ***never changes***.

This code:

```
if(index > 0 || index <iSize){
   throw new IllegalArgumentException("index (" + index + ") must be greater than zero and less than size iSize + ")"); 
}
```

Think about it. `||` is "or", yet the error message says "and"

You still haven't fixed the doubling-the-array-yet-only-incrementing-`size` problem, nor the `asData[index] != ""` issue, as mentioned in my original answer.